# Updating different $scope object properties via ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Please look at the code below. 
Why does the `$scope.data` variable not update, when inserting valid values in the input fields?
How can I achieve this?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/uloco/pen/jboorN

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController" class="content">
    <input type="tel" ng-model="form.phone" placeholder="phone" />
    <input type="email" ng-model="form.email" placeholder="email" />
    <p>{{form}}</p>
    <p>{{data}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.data = {
        foo: 'bar',
        phone: $scope.form.phone,
        email: $scope.form.email
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the $scope.data variable not update?

Because there is no connection between `$scope.data` and `$scope.form`. Those are two separate objects with independent properties, and you are changing properties of the `$scope.form`.

If you really want to have two *separate* objects you will need to sync them manually either with `$scope.$watch` on the `$scope.form`

```
$scope.$watch('form', function(obj) {
    $scope.data.phone = obj.phone;
    $scope.data.email = obj.email;
}, true);
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPvvBr?editors=101

or with `ngChange` directives:

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="form.phone" placeholder="phone" ng-change="sync()" />
<input type="email" ng-model="form.email" placeholder="email" ng-change="sync()" />
```

and

```
$scope.sync = function() {
    $scope.data.phone = $scope.form.phone;
    $scope.data.email = $scope.form.email;
};
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVyyQN?editors=101

`ngChange` solution is preferred in this case. However, if you have more then 2 fields then $watch could be simpler.

Comment: This is better than my answer. Use watch.

Comment: No, I think it add an extra watch, so for better performance ng-change is much preferable.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I also think ngChange is better, at least for small number of fields.

Comment: I need two separate objects, because one of them is a super set of the other. What I actually want is inserting the `$scope.data` value in a custom directive and this should update as I am changing the `ng-model` value.

Comment: Could this also be achieved with a getter/setter via ng-model-settings?

Comment: Just use dot rule. So instead of copying values (no reference) copy reference to object: `$scope.data = {foo: 'bar', form: $scope.form}`. Then use `$scope.data.form.phone` and you will not need no watchers or other shenanigans.

Comment: Yes I know that, but in my special case, I need to assign only a subset of the form object to the data. This is not shown in this code sample I know. Like that: `$scope.form = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'bar'}; $scope.data = {foo: $scope.form.foo, bar: $scope.form.bar}`. Notice that `baz` is missing here.

Answer (score 3):

you can try add ng-change:

```
 $scope.change = function(data){
        $scope.data.phone = data.phone;
        $scope.data.email = data.email;
    };
```

and on Html

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="form.phone" placeholder="phone" ng-change="change(form);"/>
<input type="email" ng-model="form.email" placeholder="email" ng-change="change(form);"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.form.phone and $scope.form.email are assigned at controller setup where they are both undefined. Even if $scope.form changes, $scope.data does not know because all it stores is "undefined".

To retrieve the data, you could implement a function like so:

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    return {
        foo: 'bar',
        phone: $scope.form.phone,
        email: $scope.form.email
    };
};
```

This makes sure that the object is freshly initialized when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope.data is being asigned once and not being change on phone or email change.

Try to use **$watchGroup**

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['form.phone', 'form.email'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
  scope.data = {
        foo: 'bar',
        phone: scope.form.phone,
        email: scope.form.email
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController" class="content">
    <input type="tel" ng-model="form.phone" placeholder="phone" />
    <input type="email" ng-model="form.email" placeholder="email" />
    <p>form: {{form}}</p>
    <p>data: {{data()}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
        $scope.form = {};
        $scope.data = function() {
            return {
                foo: 'bar',
                phone: $scope.form.phone,
                email: $scope.form.email
            };
        }
    });
```

updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xmwwye